# Is it possible to stop the changing format of a double precision no. in a <fr:currency> field?

Tags: double, currency, orbeon, xforms

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:odt="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/datatypes"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
    xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
    xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
    xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">

    <xhtml:head>


        <xforms:model id="model">


        <xforms:instance id="test">
            <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <add>
                    <value></value>
                    <result></result>
                </add>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>  



                <xforms:bind id="value" nodeset="instance('test')/add/value" />
                <xforms:bind id="result" nodeset="instance('test')/add/result" calculate="number(../value) * 2" />

        </xforms:model>
    </xhtml:head>

    <xhtml:body>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Value</td>
                <td>
                    <fr:currency bind="value" incremental="true">
                    </fr:currency>
                </td>
                <td>* 2  =</td>
                <td></td><td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <fr:currency bind="result" incremental="true">
                    </fr:currency>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

In the above program, the second textbox is calculated by multiplying the value*2. If a value of 345 is given in the Value textbox, it gives 690 in the next textbox. But when a value of 3453456 is provided, it gives a value of 6.90. I know this is because of the double precision value. but I do not want this to happen and want the real value to be displayed. How can I execute this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an XSLT stylesheet on the element to apply the [format-number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#function-format-number) method on the value. `Number` coercion of the entire expression may also work:

```
Number(Number(../value) * 2)
```